# Magento 1.9 CMS Pages changing content format while saving

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages, magento1.9.3.7

I am saving my HTML content in CMS pages of Magento 1.9.3.7. But It's changing the format of my HTML content and adding a slash when a doublequote found in the code.
For example when I save below code:

```
<h1 align="center">How To Find Us</h1>
```

It changes it after saving and change it to :

```
<h1 align=\"center\">How To Find Us</h1>
```

Please help tme to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does that happen with every node attribute? eg also class="foobar"

Comment: yes, It happens for each and every node attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason. Actually I was using the https://www.tripleginteractive.com/blog/wordpress/integrate-magento-wordpress/ solution to use WP functions inside magento and written the code in index.php file that why it was happening. Now I have placed that code in that particular file only where I am using WP functions.

Hope It helps someone in future.

Comment: great.......... :)